# c# loop listbox selected items

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox on a form set to allow multiple selections. I want to loop through each selected item, store the selected value in a variable and do some work. I've tried many different variations of code to do this, but so far nothing has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My code is below:

```
foreach (var item in systemList.Items)
{
    string systemName = systemList.SelectedItems.ToString();
    //do some work//
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all `SelectedItems` using below code:

```
var items = systemList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
```

You can then loop through the items

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    //Access value of each item by calling item.Value
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggested code and I get this error for ListItem: 'the type or namespace name 'listitem' could not be found.'

Comment: ohho... you should be able to find the relevant namespaces required to do this job; try adding one or both of these usings - using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in systemList.SelectedItems)
        {
            string systemName = item.ToString();
            //do some work//
        }
```

make sure listbox Selection mode is set to other than single!